# Transform comma separated string into a list but ignore comma in quotes

Tags: python, regex, split, delimiter

How do I convert `"1,,2'3,4'"` into a list? Commas separate the individual items, unless they are within quotes. In that case, the comma is to be included in the item.

This is the desired result: `['1', '', '2', '3,4']`. One regex I found on another thread to ignore the quotes is as follows:

```
re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
```

But this gives me this output:

```
['', '1', ',,', "2'3,4'", '']
```

I can't understand, where these extra empty strings are coming from, and why the two commas are even being printed at all, let alone together.

I tried making this regex myself:

```
re.compile(r'''(, | "[^"]*" | '[^']*')''')
```

which ended up not detecting anything, and just returned my original list.

I don't understand why, shouldn't it detect the commas at the very least? The same problem occurs if I add a `?` after the comma.

Comment: ... "Now you have 2 problems." Why do you need regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of a regular expression, you might be better off using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module since what you are dealing with is a CSV string:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from csv import reader

file_like_object = StringIO("1,,2,'3,4'")
csv_reader = reader(file_like_object, quotechar="'")
for row in csv_reader:
    print row
```

This results in the following output:

```
['1', '', '2', '3,4']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this ran into the same problem as split(','), which is that it separated the comma between the 3 and 4.  It's why I was trying to use regex

Comment: @masahane - oops - you need to add `quotechar="'"` to the `reader` call. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

pyparsing includes a predefined expression for comma-separated lists:

```
>>> from pyparsing import commaSeparatedList
>>> s = "1,,2'3,4'"
>>> print commaSeparatedList.parseString(s).asList()
['1', '', "2'3", "4'"]
```

Hmm, looks like you have a typo in your data, missing a comma after the 2:

```
>>> s = "1,,2,'3,4'"
>>> print commaSeparatedList.parseString(s).asList()
['1', '', '2', "'3,4'"]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Don't have enough reputation to upvote, sadly.