# Split a Python string with nested separated symbol

Tags: python, regex, string

I need from string

```
i = "1,'Test','items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"
```

extract array of next strings:

```
['1', "'Test'", "'items (one, two, etc.)'", '1', "'long, list'"]
```

with help of regexpress

```
r=re.split(r',+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))', i)
```

I receive next result only:

```
['1', "'Test'", "'items (one, two, etc.)'", '1', "'long", " list'"]
```

**UPD1**

**NULL** should be supported

```
i = "1,'Test',NULL,'items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"
['1', "'Test'", 'NULL', "'items (one, two, etc.)'", '1', "'long, list'"]
```

Comment: why doesnt `i.split(',')` work as a solution?

Comment: @letsc It will also split `one, two, etc.` and `'long, list'` in quotes.

Comment: Although it's not quite what you asked for, you may actually want the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module instead of regexes (see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805535/transform-comma-separated-string-into-a-list-but-ignore-comma-in-quotes) question).

Comment: @alcedine I did not read your comment until now. My solution is the same as the one you suggest, but I did not copy from it :-)

Comment: What's with **NULL**? It is just another string in Python

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `re.split` in this case.you can use `re.findall` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> [k for j in re.findall(r"(\d)|'([^']*)'",i) for k in j if k]
['1', 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']
```

The preceding regex will match any thing between one quote `'([^']*)'` or any digit (`\d`).

Or as a more efficient way in this case you can use `ast.literal_eval` :

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(i)
(1, 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', 1, 'long, list')
```

Comment: in line "i = "1,'Test',NULL,'items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'""  NULL ignored. How to update suggested code to support NULL too?

Comment: @constructor If your problem is just `NULL` use `>>> [k for j in re.findall(r"(\d)|'([^']*)'|(NULL)",i) for k in j if k]`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I parse SQL file and have a problems. I am sure that I am not first. Solution of part of problems found and implemented in my code. I cannot solution (regexp) the published sample.

Answer (score 2):

This is a task for the `csv` module:

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
line = "1,'Test','items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(line), quotechar="'")
row = next(reader)

# row == ['1', 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']
```

The key here is to create a CSV reader, specifying single quote as the quote character.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on single quotes:

```
i = "1,'Test','items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"



print([ele.strip(" ,") for ele in i.split("'") if ele.strip(",")])
['1', 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']
```

Or use it with map:

```
print([ele for ele in map(lambda x:  x.strip(", "), i.split("'")) if ele])
```

Using map with python 3 is pretty efficient:

```
In [7]: i = "1,'Test','items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"

In [8]: timeit [ele for ele in map(lambda x:  x.strip(", "), i.split("'")) if ele]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 µs per loop

In [9]: r = re.compile(r"(\d)|'([^']*)'") 

In [10]: timeit [k for j in r.findall(i) for k in j if k]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.92 µs per loop
```

Better using python2 and `itertools.imap`:

```
In [9]: from itertools  import imap   
In [10]: timeit [ele for ele in imap(lambda x:  x.strip(", "), i.split("'")) if ele]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 871 ns per loop  

In [11]: r = re.compile(r"(\d)|'([^']*)'")
In [12]: timeit [k for j in r.findall(i) for k in j if k]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.27 µs per loop

In [17]: from ast import literal_eval
In [18]: timeit literal_eval(i)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.2 µs per loop
```

All of which return the same output bar literal_eval as it evaluates the numbers as ints:

```
In [19]: literal_eval(i)
Out[19]: (1, 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', 1, 'long, list')

In [20]: [k for j in r.findall(i) for k in j if k]
Out[20]: ['1', 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']

In [21]: [ele for ele in imap(lambda x:  x.strip(", "), i.split("'")) if ele]Out[21]: ['1', 'Test', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']
```

There is nothing different with the NUll line:

```
i = "1,'Test',NULL,'items (one, two, etc.)',1,'long, list'"



print([ele for ele in map(lambda x:  x.strip(", "), i.split("'")) if ele])

['1', 'Test', 'NULL', 'items (one, two, etc.)', '1', 'long, list']
```